# Meaning of (special) derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Assume I have a function $f(a(x),b(x))$. What is the meaning of $\frac{df}{db}$? Can I say that this derivative is the change in $f$ due to infinitesimal change in value of function $b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here. First, $f(a(x),b(x))$ is **not a function**. $f:(a,b)\mapsto f(a,b)$ is truly a function, $f(a(x),b(x))$ is just this function evaluated at a particular point $(a(x),b(x))$. If we let $a,b$ be functions we can define
$$g(x)=f(a(x),b(x))$$
What you mean when you write the somewhat nonsensical expression $df/db$ is actually $\partial_2 f$, which means the partial derivative with respect to the second argument of $f$. If we want to **name** the first and second arguments of $f$ $a$ and $b$ we can write this as $\partial_b f$ which, theoretically we should avoid, but it often makes the mathematics easier to read and understand. We could also make use of the chain rule to write
$$(\mathrm D g)(x)=(\partial_1 f)(a(x),b(x))~ (\mathrm D a)(x)+(\partial_2 f)(a(x),b(x))~(\mathrm D b)(x)$$
Which is the most exact way of writing this, but the downside is it is unwieldy and hard to remember. In a more classical notation one might write
$$g'(x)=a'(x)\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}(a(x),b(x))+b'(x)\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}(a(x),b(x))$$
Which although more compact, is less exact. This tradeoff is common in math.

Comment: Thank you! But what if $a(x)=x$? What is the meaning of the derivative with respect to the second input (in terms of limits when $\Delta x$ approaches 0) in that case?

Comment: @Alex Regardless of what $a(x)$ is the meaning is the same. $\partial_b f$ is the rate of change in $f$ due to a small change in the second argument, while holding the first argument fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the classic notation problem in multivariate calculus.
In my experience, the meaning of $\frac{df}{db}$ in this case would be the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to the second input, which is the input that the value of the function $b$ is inserted into.
So yes, this derivative can be thought of as the change in $f$ due to an infinitesimal change in $b$, though I advise to simply think of it as exactly what I described it as: the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to the second input.
Much less confusing, in my opinion.

Comment: Great answer. Although useful, Leibniz notation suffers from the problem that it gives *meaning* to the name that we decide to call the arguments of a function, when in fact no such meaning should exist.